# rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I upload document file(pdf, docx) to database(mysql)? I researched on this topic and there are few guides on this. I tried several methods, but I cannot upload and I have no idea how to do that, spring has guide on this but it shows how to upload to file system not into database. Thank you.

my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")
public class Document {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "reg_id", nullable = false)
    private String registrationId;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "reg_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate registrationDate;

    @Column(name = "doc_id")
    private String documentId;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "doc_date")
    private LocalDate documentDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "correspondent_id")
    private Correspondent correspondent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "delivery_id")
    private Delivery delivery;

    @Column(name = "doc_subject", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String documentSubject;

    @Column(name = "doc_description", length = 1000)
    private String documentDescription;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "doc_deadline")
    private LocalDate documentDeadline;

    @Column(name = "doc_authority", length = 3)
    private String documentAuthority;

    @Column(name = "doc_control", length = 3)
    private String documentControl;

    @Column(name = "file_name", length = 50)
    private String documentName;

    @Column(name = "file_type", length = 30)
    private String documentType;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "file_doc")
    private byte[] documentFile;

    //getters and setters
```

my upload form(thymeleaf)

```
<body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px">
        <h1 class="h1" style="text-align: center;">Добавить новый документ</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${document}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label th:for="registrationId"><strong>Рег. №</strong></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{registrationId}" placeholder="Регистрационный номер" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label th:for="documentId"><strong>№ исх. док-та</strong></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{documentId}" placeholder="Номер исходного документа" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row" style="margin-top: 15px">
                <div class="col">
                    <label th:for="registrationDate"><strong>Дата рег.</strong></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" th:field="*{registrationDate}" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label th:for="documentDate"><strong>Дата исх. док-та</strong></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" th:field="*{documentDate}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px">
                <label th:for="deliveryType"><strong>Форма доставки</strong></label>
                <select name="deliveryId" class="browser-default custom-select">
                    <option th:each="delivery : ${deliveries}"
                            th:text="${delivery.deliveryType}"
                            th:value="${delivery.id}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label th:for="correspondent"><strong>Корреспондент</strong></label>
                <select name="correspondentId" class="browser-default custom-select">
                    <option th:each="correspondent : ${correspondents}"
                            th:text="${correspondent.correspondent}"
                            th:value="${correspondent.id}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label th:for="documentSubject"><strong>Тема</strong></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{documentSubject}" placeholder="Тема" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label th:for="documentDescription"><strong>Описание</strong></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{documentDescription}" placeholder="Описание" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label th:for="documentDeadline"><strong>Срок исполнения</strong></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="date" th:field="*{documentDeadline}" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label th:for="documentAuthority"><strong>Доступ</strong></label>
                    <select class="browser-default custom-select" th:field="*{documentAuthority}">
                        <option value="Нет">Нет</option>
                        <option value="Да">Да</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label th:for="documentControl"><strong>Контроль</strong></label>
                    <select class="browser-default custom-select" th:field="*{documentControl}">
                        <option value="Нет">Нет</option>
                        <option value="Да">Да</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label th:for="documentFile"><strong>Выбрать документ</strong></label>
                <input type="file" name="file" th:field="*{documentFile}"/>
            </div>
            <div style="height: 100px; margin-top: 20px">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Сохранить" />
                <a href="/"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Все документы" /></a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

service class(logic)

```
@Service
public class DocumentServiceImpl implements DocumentService {

    private final DocumentRepository documentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DocumentServiceImpl(DocumentRepository documentRepository) {
        this.documentRepository = documentRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Document> findAllDocuments() {
        return documentRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveDocument(Document document) {
        documentRepository.save(document);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Document> getDocumentByRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
        return documentRepository.findById(registrationId);
    }
}
```

my controller

```
@Controller
public class DocumentController {

    private final DocumentServiceImpl documentService;

    private final CorrespondentServiceImpl correspondentService;

    private final DeliveryServiceImpl deliveryService;

    @Autowired
    public DocumentController(DocumentServiceImpl documentService, CorrespondentServiceImpl correspondentService, DeliveryServiceImpl deliveryService) {
        this.documentService = documentService;
        this.correspondentService = correspondentService;
        this.deliveryService = deliveryService;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = {"/", "/home"})
    public String listAllDocuments(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("documents", documentService.findAllDocuments());
        return "all";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/add")
    public String addNewDocument(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new Document());
        model.addAttribute("correspondents", correspondentService.findAllCorrespondents());
        model.addAttribute("deliveries", deliveryService.findAllDeliveryTypes());
        return "add";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/add")
    public String addNewDocumentForm(@ModelAttribute Document document,
                                     @RequestParam Byte correspondentId,
                                     @RequestParam Byte deliveryId,
                                     @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException {
        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            if (file.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка, загрузите файл снова!");
            } else {
                Correspondent correspondent = new Correspondent();
                correspondent.setId(correspondentId);

                Delivery delivery = new Delivery();
                delivery.setId(deliveryId);

                document.setCorrespondent(correspondent);
                document.setDelivery(delivery);

                String documentName = file.getOriginalFilename();

                FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file.getInputStream(), new File(Objects.requireNonNull(file.getOriginalFilename())));
                document.setDocumentName(documentName);
                document.setDocumentType(file.getContentType());
                document.setDocumentFile(file.getBytes());
                documentService.saveDocument(document);
            }
        }

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

StackTrace

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

2020-07-21 18:32:13.871  INFO 9068 --- [           main] c.t.f.D.Form.DocumentFormApplication     : Starting DocumentFormApplication on DESKTOP-RLOD3FO with PID 9068 (D:\My Projects\Document-Form\target\classes started by camer in D:\My Projects\Document-Form)
2020-07-21 18:32:13.874  INFO 9068 --- [           main] c.t.f.D.Form.DocumentFormApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-07-21 18:32:14.477  INFO 9068 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-07-21 18:32:14.580  INFO 9068 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 63ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-07-21 18:32:14.941  INFO 9068 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-07-21 18:32:14.946  INFO 9068 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-07-21 18:32:14.946  INFO 9068 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
2020-07-21 18:32:15.044  INFO 9068 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-07-21 18:32:15.044  INFO 9068 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1136 ms
2020-07-21 18:32:15.150  INFO 9068 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-07-21 18:32:15.183  INFO 9068 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-07-21 18:32:15.203  WARN 9068 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-07-21 18:32:15.210  INFO 9068 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.17.Final
2020-07-21 18:32:15.295  INFO 9068 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-07-21 18:32:15.356  INFO 9068 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-07-21 18:32:15.477  INFO 9068 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-07-21 18:32:15.478  INFO 9068 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-07-21 18:32:15.821  INFO 9068 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-07-21 18:32:15.834  INFO 9068 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-07-21 18:32:16.279  INFO 9068 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-07-21 18:32:16.285  INFO 9068 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-07-21 18:32:16.401  INFO 9068 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-07-21 18:32:16.407  INFO 9068 --- [           main] c.t.f.D.Form.DocumentFormApplication     : Started DocumentFormApplication in 2.794 seconds (JVM running for 3.505)
2020-07-21 18:32:27.098  INFO 9068 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-07-21 18:32:27.099  INFO 9068 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-07-21 18:32:27.104  INFO 9068 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms
2020-07-21 18:32:39.827  WARN 9068 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'document' on field 'documentFile': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@15771ea0]; codes [typeMismatch.document.documentFile,typeMismatch.documentFile,typeMismatch.[B,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [document.documentFile,documentFile]; arguments []; default message [documentFile]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte[]' for property 'documentFile'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte' for property 'documentFile[0]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile']]
2020-07-21 18:32:55.426  WARN 9068 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'document' on field 'documentFile': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@42ef89f3]; codes [typeMismatch.document.documentFile,typeMismatch.documentFile,typeMismatch.[B,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [document.documentFile,documentFile]; arguments []; default message [documentFile]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte[]' for property 'documentFile'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte' for property 'documentFile[0]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile']]
```

Comment: Why saving files in database? Also you have many things to review, why did you defined interfaces if you do not use them?

Comment: I will implement business logic in future, the files must not weigh more than 1MB that's why I decided to store them in database!

Comment: remove the `th:field` from your file field and rename the field to `files` instead of `file` else it won't bind to the `@RequestParam` you have defined.

Comment: It is much more common to save the name of the file as string to your database and search for it via the name in classpath.

Comment: Thank you very much, it finally worked!

Comment: Thank you M. Deinum!